# How do I set an unnamed column as the index?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, indexing

In all the examples I have found, a column name is usually required to set it as the index

Instead of going into excel to add a column header, I was wondering if it's possible to set an empty header as the index. The column has all the values I want included, but lacks a column name:

[image]

My script is currently:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
data
```

Comment: Are you sure it has no column name? the empty string `''` is probably its "name"

Comment: I've tried using:

`data = data.set_index(' ')

But I get `KeyError: ' '`


I also tried: 
`data = data.set_index('')` but this also results in an error

Comment: Have you looked at what `data.columns` says it's called?

Comment: greg, I inputted `data.columns` and I get `Index(['        ', '    K37L', '    K37M', '    K37N', '    K37P', '    K37Q',
       '    K37R', '    K37S', '    K37T', '    K37U', '    K37V', '    K37W',
       '    K37X', '    K37Y', '    K37Z', '    K382', '    K383', '    K384',
       '    K385', '    K386', '    K387', '    K388', '    K389', '    K38A',
       '    K38B', '    K38C', '    K38D', '    K38E'],
      dtype='object')`

Comment: I copied and pasted `'        '` into `data.set_index()` and it still returns with KeyError

Comment: fair enough, that is odd. Renaming as described in the answer below should definitely still work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to rename the first column in excel. It's as easy in pandas as well:

```
new_columns = data.columns.values
new_columns[0] = 'Month'
data.columns = new_columns
```

Afterwards, you can set the index:

```
data = data.set_index('Month')
```

Comment: @kyle 's answer is succinct, but this answer is useful when you get the following error "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py:569: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  mask |= (ar1 == a)". This answer solves this problem.

Answer (score 15):

You could also just select the column by id with `iloc`:

```
data = data.set_index(data.iloc[:, 0])
```

Or when you call `pd.read_csv()`, specify `index_col`:

```
data = pd.read_csv('path.csv', index_col=0)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('file.csv',index_col=0)
data
```

Comment: This is likely what most people need when they come looking for answers. Nice.

Comment: This is should have been the straight forward answer.

Answer (score 0):

When I have encountered columns missing names, Pandas always name them 'Unnamed: n', where n = ColumnNumber-1. ie 'Unnamed: 0' for first column, 'Unnamed: 1' for second etc. So I think that in your case the following code should be useful:

```
# set your column as the dataframe index
data.index = data['Unnamed: 0']
# now delete the column
data.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1, inplace=True)
# also delete the index name which was 'Unnamed: 0' obviously
del data.index.name
```

Comment: Since Pandas 1.0.3 this is no longer possible as it raises an error. Instead the name can be set to None: `data.index.name = None`